# Selector for select elements with names that don't start/end with "something"

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

In jQuery it's possible to select all elements that start/end with "something".

```
 = is exactly equal
!= is not equal
^= starts with
$= ends with
```

Is it possible to select all elements that don't start/end with "something"?

Comment: A bit confusing. Do you also need a selector which excludes names that are ending with "something" or just those which start with "something"?

Comment: Neither start *nor* end with `something`? I would recommend `$('yourSelector').not('[id^=something], [id$=something]')`.

Comment: It was just a hypothetical question. My intention was for elements that don't start **or** don't end with `something`, but that's actually a pretty good idea for when both are needed at the same time.

Comment: that seems like a way too theorical approach, I don't see any real-world scenarios where you would ever want a selector that doesn't begin nor end with something, you should consider having better semantics as a fix for that instead.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the [`:not`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector:

```
:not([id^=foo])
```